# C# program does not evaluate operations and return wrong answers

Tags: c#, windows, oop, cmd, notepad++

Community.

I am learning how to program in C#. I wrote this small program that gets the name, age, favorite color, and two numbers from the user. I use Notepad ++ to write the code and run the C# compiler from the windows command prompt. Here is the source code of the program

```
using System;

class ShowSomething
{
static void Main(string[] args)

{
    string name, age, favColor;
    int num1,num2, sum, mult, subs;
    float div;


    Console.Write("What is your name? ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.Write("How old are you? ");
    age = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("So you are " + age, "I thought that you were older!");

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.Write("What is your favorite Color? ");
    favColor = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(favColor + " is a cool color!");

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Nice meeting you, " + name, "Have a good day!");

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Let us do some operations, " + name);

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
    num1 = Console.Read();

    Console.Write("Please enter another number: ");
    num2 = Console.Read();

    sum = num1 + num2;
    mult = num1 * num2;
    subs = num1 - num2;
    div = num1 / num2;


    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Alright, " + name, "Let us blow up your mind!");

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine(num1 + "+" + num2, "=" + sum);
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + "*" + num2, "=" + mult);
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + "-" + num2, "=" + subs);
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + "/" + num2, "=" + div);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Mindblown, Right?");
}   

}
```

When I execute the program almost everything goes alright. However, when the user inputs the first number of the operations, the program skips the second prompt and print a completely different result from the one expected. For example, if I put 0 as the first number the program will jump to the operations and print the following:

//

48+13

48*13

48-13

48/13

Mindblown, right?

//

Comment: This behavior is by design. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx

Comment: Why write in a text editor and compile manually? C# Express is free and will help you learn many times faster

Comment: Sidenote, are you sure that this `Console.WriteLine("Nice meeting you, " + name, "Have a good day!");` does what you think it does?

Comment: The "Mindblown" comment is a little reward to myself for compiling the program without any problems. At least syntax problems...

Comment: @NikBougalis just noticed that extra piece of text. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Brad I rather write the code myself and debug any problems or ask someone else for directions. I find the Visual C# express 2012 hints and notes annoying

Comment: What hints and notes? And it includes a debugger. What's wrong with being told about syntax errors immediately instead of waiting for a compilation?

Comment: @JohnSaunders There is nothing wrong with being told about syntax errors, but I rather force myself think a lot about what I'm doing before I start writing the code. I consider the compilation errors that come from compiling from cmd as a negative reinforcement to do things right.

Comment: @Jameslat: to each his own. I have better things to do with my time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use [`Console.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) as it does not do what is expected:

> Reads the next character from the standard input stream (and returns the integer value<sup>1</sup> that represents it).

Here a good explanation from devshort on why the second call to `Console.Read` "skips":

> If you enter in the value "1" for the first thing, it'll convert that to the ascii representation. Then the carriage return is STILL in the screen [input] buffer, so when you hit the next read (Console.Read) it reads the newline and converts it to a number.

Instead, one approach is to use [`Console.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) instead (which returns a string) in conjunction with [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) or similar ..

---

<sup>1</sup> Hint: the [carriage return](http://www.asciitable.com) character has a value of 13.

Comment: This. If you enter in the value "1" for the first thing, it'll convert that to the ascii representation.  Then the carriage return is STILL in the screen buffer, so when you hit the next `Read` it reads the newline and converts it to a number.  If you input more than 1 character for the first input it'll read the first character then the second read will read the second character.  Mind not blown. Do this instead of your read: `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: @devshorts Indeed. Thanks for the explanation on the skipping behavior.

Comment: I wanted to change my comment to not use Convert.ToInt32 since that will throw an exception if the input string is invalid. Do what @pst said and use int.Parse: 

`if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number! ");
            }`

Comment: Thank you all  for the answers. I got the program running without any problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The ascii that is visually `0` has a byte value of 48. or `0x30`. Which explains the 48.

Basically, you're using the wrong function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I edited your code a little and added some explanation wy I changed somethings..

```
        string name, age, favColor;
        int num1, num2, sum, mult, subs; 
        float div;


        Console.WriteLine("What is your name? "); 
        //Start a new line and write ..
        name = Console.ReadLine(); 
        //Read the whole line
        Console.WriteLine("\nHello, {0}", name); 
        //{0} stands for the first variable you refer to after the, etc

        Console.WriteLine("How old are you? ");
        age = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nSo you are {0}, I thought that you were older!", age);
        // something new.. \n refers to a "new line", so instead of writing Console.Writeline(); you can use this
        Console.WriteLine("What is your favorite Color? ");
        favColor = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a cool color!\n", favColor);

        Console.WriteLine("Nice meeting you, {0}", name);
        Console.WriteLine("Have a good day!\n");


        Console.WriteLine("Let us do some operations, {0}", name);

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
        num1 =  Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        //int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1);
        //Another way is to "try parse", try converting a string to an integer


        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter another number: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        //int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num2);
        //Another way is to "try parse", try converting a string to an integer where out is the returning variable

        sum = num1 + num2;
        mult = num1 * num2;
        subs = num1 - num2;
        div = num1 / num2;



        Console.WriteLine("\nAlright, {0}", name);
        Console.WriteLine("Let us blow up your mind!\n");

        //Again use {0} ... which writes easier than having to use + every time,
        //its not wrong but its easier this way
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, sum);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", num1, num2, mult);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", num1, num2, subs);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", num1, num2, div);

        Console.WriteLine("\nMindblown, Right?");
        Console.ReadLine();
        //Console.ReadLine(); at the end to prevent the program from closing
```

Comment: @JamesSlat If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: @C# Student

Thanks for the corrections! It looks way more cleaner and organized than my previous source code. I didn't know about the "\n" or the "{0}", but they seem like a better way to print a blank line and write the values of the variables.

Comment: @C# Student ¿What's the difference between Convert.ToInt16, Convert.ToInt32, and int.Parse? It seems that they can be useful depending on the situation.

Comment: @Jameslat Here's an good example about difference between convert and parse and tryparse: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32885/Difference-Between-Int32-Parse-Convert-ToInt32-and

Difference between Convert.ToInt16 and Int32 would be the range of allowed values, you can see that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/exx3b86w.aspx

I mostly use int.TryParse so when there's an incorrect user input, it returns either 0 or the correct value. And the program still runs, instead of getting stuck on that 1 error.